# Create a node's author by passing an argument...?

Tags: views, users

I have a view in which I can see a list of all my users.

I would like to be able to click on one of the names in this list and create a node and have the user that I clicked on be the author of this new node.

Is it possible to do this by passing an argument in the URL, or perhaps there is an easier way to do this that I had not thought of.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use views rewrite on username field to create a "create node" link and [prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module using tokens from the views. In this case the username token for the author field.

Comment: Thanks Dee, I will certainly attempt this. I notice that the prepopulate module is in dev for D7. Have you used it and found it stable enough for your needs?

Comment: I have used it several times and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dee for the idea.

Turns out that use the prepopulate module was indeed the correct way.

One thing to watch is that if you want to create an author using prepopulate, you need to write:

```
[author][name]=[name]
```

The `[name]` in `[author][name]` will get turned into the username in that token...

So use `[author]%5Bname%5D` instead - worked for me...